# How to synchronize Azure Mobile Services Offline Sync from an Xamarin app

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

previously, there was the possibility of creating an app services in azure that allowed you to connect an SQL database through the creation of "Easy Tables" but this will be deleted on November 11 (https://aka.ms/easydeprecation), but you can no longer add more tables this way, but you have to do it by the App Service Editor (preliminary version).

I can create the table as the link attached says, the problem is that when I synchronize my data from my xamarin app it says that the resource does not exist or has been removed, that it has been changed or that it is temporarily unavailable.

I think the problem is some configuration or package or extension that I must install in this new app services but I cannot identify it.

My code C #

```
public async Task SyncAllAsync(bool SyncForce = false)
        {

            ReadOnlyCollection<MobileServiceTableOperationError> syncErrors = null;
            long PendingChanges = CurrentClient.SyncContext.PendingOperations;
            try
            {
                await CurrentClient.SyncContext.PushAsync();

                await PatientTable.PullAsync("SyncPatientAsync", PatientTable.CreateQuery());

            }
            catch (MobileServicePushFailedException exc)
            {
                if (exc.PushResult != null)
                {
                    syncErrors = exc.PushResult.Errors;
                }
            }

            // Simple error/conflict handling. A real application would handle the various errors like network conditions,
            // server conflicts and others via the IMobileServiceSyncHandler.
            if (syncErrors != null)
            {
                foreach (MobileServiceTableOperationError error in syncErrors)
                {
                    if (error.OperationKind == MobileServiceTableOperationKind.Update && error.Result != null)
                    {
                        //Update failed, reverting to server's copy.
                        await error.CancelAndUpdateItemAsync(error.Result);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Discard local change.
                        await error.CancelAndDiscardItemAsync();
                    }

                    string message = "Error executing sync operation. Item: " + error.TableName + " (" + error.Item["id"] + "). Operation discarded.";

                    Debug.WriteLine(message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Patient.json

```
{
      "softDelete" : true,
      "autoIncrement": false,
  "insert": {
    "access": "anonymous"
  },
  "update": {
    "access": "anonymous"
  },
  "delete": {
    "access": "anonymous"
  },
  "read": {
    "access": "anonymous"
  },
  "undelete": {
    "access": "anonymous"
  }}
```

Patient.js

```
var table = module.exports = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();

// table.read(function (context) {
//     return context.execute();
// });

// table.read.use(customMiddleware, table.operation);
```

Comment: What does the structure of your new table look like? Does it have the id, createdAt, updatedAt, and deleted columns?

Comment: @EricHedstrom Hello, after many attempts I realized that the error is the database connection string that had a small error, once I corrected it, the synchronization started again as expected. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The Easy Tables is just a Web API - each table is at https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/tables/yourtable and the pull operation basically does something like `GET https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/tables/yourtable?filter=(UpdatedAt ge datetimeoffset'some-iso-date')`.  Enable logging on your Xamarin host ([details here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/blob/master/samples/xamarin-forms/ZumoQuickstart/ZumoQuickstart/TodoService.cs#L58) plus the end of the same file) to see the actual HTTP requests that are happening.

The error you are receiving is probably a 404.  Common issues:

- You specified http instead of https in the client
- The name of the table is wrong